# Set "Treat wchar_t as Built-in Type" Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, project-properties

Can anyone tell me, please. How can i set  "Treat wchar_t as Built-in Type" in Visual Studio 2012. In main documentation i see, that a i have to set like [here](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_Ac0gUZe6XLk/R-s1OFT1gyI/AAAAAAAAAEs/mmnu1I4iZFo/s1600/wchar.png)
Bu in VS2012 in project properties i see only this:
[sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJw51.png)
Thanks for yu help!

Answer (score 3):

Right click on c++ project (NOT solution) and select properties, you should see something like this [image]